# how can i change display format in datawindow rather than display data in vertical

Tags: datawindow

powerbuilder.net

What it look like[image: vertical]

what I want its look:
[image: Horizontal]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the N-Up datawindow style otherwise you could flatten the data in SQL using one of the examples in this [stackoverflow question on flattening data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651511/trying-to-flatten-rows-into-columns) the method you would use might depend on if you know how many occurs there are. If you need the data to be update-able then you'll need to write some code to un-flatten on save.